# Customizing active_admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization, activeadmin

I've a simple question about active admin interface.

In my application, I've a resource added to the active_admin. When I access the resource from active_admin, I get all records for that resource. When I select/access (as a show action) one record it shows details of that instance and all belongs_to associations but I don't know how to get the has_many or has_one association details in the show view?

Any ideas? I appreciate any feedback.

Thanks,
Atarang.

Comment: One way is to set instance variables in controller and access them in view. For example if Study has_many Subjects. then in controlller instantiate '@subjects = @study.subjects'. Then use '@subjects' in scriplet to render subjects

Comment: That's true but how do you access this association from active_admin interface?

Answer (score 4):

You need to customize your show screen in app/admin/yourresource.rb.  You shouldn't need to do anything special otherwise, other than making sure the has_many and belongs_to associations are correct.  For example, if you have a category with many items, do this in category.rb:

```
show :category do
  panel "Category Info" do
    attributes_table_for category, :name, :created_at
  end
  panel "Items in This Category" do
    table_for(category.items) do
      column("Name", :sortable => :name) {|item| item.name }
      column("Created At") {|item| item.created_at }
    end
  end
end
```

There are more good examples [here](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info/blob/master/app/admin/users.rb) and [elsewhere](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info/tree/master/app/admin) in the source for the demo project, which for some reason is hard to find from the main site.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this and other resources mentioned. Thanks again.